# Oracle Provider for .NET won't find newly added fields/columns in entity/table using Entity Framework (ORA-00904 is thrown)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm performing some maintenance work on a legacy system which can be a bit cumbersome to work with, and I'm running into an issue that, probably due to my lack of Oracle skills I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I need to add four new columns in a given table which, even though the system does use EF for database manipulation, it wasn't done with the much preferred code-first approach when it was first idealized. The entity is huge, so here's just a little snippet of the class itself before my changes:

```
[Table("SERVICO", Schema = "SCI")]
public class Servico
{
    [DisplayName(@"Data e Hora da Solicitação")]
    [Column("DT_HORA_SOLTCAO", Order = 0), Key]
    public virtual DateTime DtHoraSoltcao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(@"Tipo de Colaborador")]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Column("TP_COLABORADOR", Order = 1), Key]
    public virtual string TpColaborador { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(@"Número de Matricula do Colaborador")]
    [Column("NR_MATRICULA_COLABORADOR", Order = 2), Key]
    public virtual int NrMatriculaColaborador { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("ID_SERVICO")]
    public virtual long IdServico { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("ID")]
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(@"Serviço Original")]
    [Column("CD_SERVICO_ORIGINAL")]
    public virtual short? CdServicoOriginal { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(@"Descrição do protocolo")]
    [Column("DS_PROTOCOLO")]
    public virtual string DsProtocolo { get; set; }

    //And so on
}
```

In this architecture, every entity has a Business Object that mostly relies on Entity Framework to do its thing. Fetching a single entry from the database in the entity above couldn't be simplier:

```
public Servico GetServicoByIdServico(long idServico)
{
    return _context.Servicos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IdServico == idServico);
}
```

Suffice to say that this has been working for over a decade. But here's the catch: I added the four forementioned fields in the `Servico` class:

```
[DisplayName(@"Diâmetro instalação esgoto")]
[Column("DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO")]
public virtual short? DmInstalEsgoto { get; set; }

[DisplayName(@"Diâmetro coletor esgoto")]
[Column("DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO")]
public virtual short? DmColetorEsgoto { get; set; }

[DisplayName(@"Ponto de Interligação")]
[Column("ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO")]
public virtual short? IdPontoInterligacao { get; set; }

[DisplayName(@"Tipo de Material de Instalação Esgoto")]
[Column("TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO")]
public virtual short? TpMaterialInstalEsgoto { get; set; }
```

I used the following script in order to generate their corresponding columns in the database:

```
BEGIN

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '-- Add/modify columns 
      alter table SERVICO add DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO Number(3,0)';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -1430 THEN RAISE; END IF;
  END;

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '-- Add/modify columns 
      alter table SERVICO add DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO Number(3,0)';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -1430 THEN RAISE; END IF;
  END;

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '-- Add/modify columns 
      alter table SERVICO add ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO Number(3,0)';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -1430 THEN RAISE; END IF;
  END;

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '-- Add/modify columns 
      alter table SERVICO add TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO Number(3,0)';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -1430 THEN RAISE; END IF;
  END;

END;
```

And then, what was supposed to be quick and easy is turning out to be a nightmare. After these changes, whenever I run the `GetServicoByIdServico` method, a `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException` is thrown:

> OracleException: ORA-00904: "Extent1"."TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO": invalid identifier

I double checked, triple checked those names, and removed one by one, testing it again every time I deleted one. But as long as one of those new fields are there (I didn't bother removing them from the database, I just deleted the properties from the `Servico` class), the last field will always raise the same exception. So I dug a little deeper. I decided to check the query EF was generating:

```
public Servico GetServicoByIdServico(long idServico)
{
    IQueryable query = from x in _context.Servicos
                       where x.IdServico == idServico
                       select x;
    //...
}
```

It is a long query, but here's the interesting part:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."DT_HORA_SOLTCAO" AS "DT_HORA_SOLTCAO", 
-- whatever
"Extent1"."DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO" AS "DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO", -- new column
"Extent1"."DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO" AS "DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO", -- new column
"Extent1"."ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO" AS "ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO", -- new column
"Extent1"."TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO" AS "TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO"-- new column
FROM "SCI"."SERVICO" "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1"."ID_SERVICO" = 1234567) -- let's say that's the ID I'm using throughout the whole thing
```

I pasted this query in my PL/SQL Developer and as it turns out, it works! So I decided in favor of a more direct approach the hopes that I was missing a setting somewhere in the C# side of things:

```
public Servico GetServicoByIdServico(long idServico)
{
    var query = $@"SELECT 
        ""Extent1"".""DT_HORA_SOLTCAO"" AS ""DT_HORA_SOLTCAO"", 
        //Ommited for brevity's sake
        ""Extent1"".""DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO"" AS ""DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO"", 
        ""Extent1"".""DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO"" AS ""DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO"", 
        ""Extent1"".""ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO"" AS ""ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO"", 
        ""Extent1"".""TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO"" AS ""TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO""
        FROM ""SCI"".""SERVICO"" ""Extent1""
        WHERE (""Extent1"".""ID_SERVICO"" = :param1)";

    OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("param1", 1234567);
    object[] parameters = new object[] { p };
    var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<object>(query, parameters).FirstOrDefault();
    
    //...
}
```

But as long as one of those four new fields are there, an ORA-00904 will be raised. I used a plain `object` instead of `Servico` as the type parameter for `SqlQuery` to purposedly bypass that class in this test. Should I remove *DM_INSTAL_ESGOTO*, *DM_COLETOR_ESGOTO*, *ID_PONTO_INTERLIGACAO* and *TP_MATERIAL_INSTAL_ESGOTO* from this hard-coded query, the method will return correctly (even though I can't see the data within it, but that's not the point here).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: From your question it does not look like a framework issue. It's an *oracle* error stating that it cannot find the new column. Are you sure that, the schema/user you using in SQL developer, is the same schema that your application connecting to? Any chance that you are mixing up different environments?

Comment: @JackySky Just checked it once again but unfortunately, this isn't the case